# How to create an alignment matrix given two lists

Tags: python, list, data-structures, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Given these two nested lists, which are the same. For example, from `a_lis` and `b_lis` are the same. However, list `a` is the reversed form of `b_lis`:

```
['Berries', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple']
```

and

```
['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'Berries']
```

`a_lis`, and `b_lis`:

```
a_lis = [['Berries', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 ['Apricots', 'peach', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 [1, 'Melons', 'strawberries', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 ['pumpkin', 'avocados', 'strawberries', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 [3, 'Melons', 'strawberries', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple']]
```

And

```
b_lis = [['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'Berries'],
 ['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach', 'Apricots'],
 ['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'strawberries', 'Melons', 1],
 ['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'strawberries', 'avocados', 'pumpkin'],
 ['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'strawberries', 'Melons', 3]]
```

How can I align them into a 2 dimensional nested list with all the possible alignments, if and only if the lists are different? For example, `['Berries', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple']`, and `['Apple', 'Orange', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'Berries']` should not be concatenated because they are the same (i.e. the first one is the reversed version from the other). This is how the expected output should look like [this](https://pastebin.com/9CQHgjHp) `(*)`:

So far, I tried to first, create a function that tell me if two lists are the same no matter its position:

```
def sequences_contain_same_items(a, b):
    for item in a:
        try:
            i = b.index(item)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        b = b[:i] + b[i+1:]
    return not b
```

Then I iterated the lists:

```
lis= []
for f, b in zip(a_lis, b_lis):
    #print(f, b)
    lis.append(f)
    lis.append(b)
print(lis)
```

However, I do not get how to produce the alignment output list. What I do not understand is if [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is the right operation to apply here. Any idea of how to produce `(*)`?

Comment: Is like a concatenated version of the Cartesian product, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a_lis = [['Berries', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 ['Apricots', 'peach', 'grapes', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 [1, 'Melons', 'strawberries', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 ['pumpkin', 'avocados', 'strawberries', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple'],
 [3, 'Melons', 'strawberries', 'lemon', 'Orange', 'Apple']]
reva = [k[-1::-1] for k in a_lis]

m = [] 
for i, v in enumerate(a_lis):
    for i1,v1 in enumerate(reva):   
        if i==i1:
            pass
        else:
            m.append(v)
            m.append(v1)
print(m)
```

---

In a more compact way,

```
m = sum([[v, v1] for i, v in enumerate(a_lis) for i1,v1 in enumerate(reva) if i!=i1], [])
```

---

```
m = [[v, v1] for i, v in enumerate(a_lis) for i1,v1 in enumerate(reva) if i!=i1]
```

Comment: @anon `m` is your expected output.  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @anon yeah, since `b_lis` is derived from `a_lis`, and in my case, `b_lis` is `reva`